# How to iterate through JSON and selectively clone portions

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string and it potentially can contain duplicate information with the exception of a price level key.

```
[{
    "id": "368",
    "type": "inventoryitem",
    "cols": {
        "id": "04-PD",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "salesdescription": "Product 1",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        }
        "internalid": {
            "name": "368",
            "internalid": "368"
        },
        "unitprice": 50.00,
        "pricelevel": {
            "name": "pricelevel1",
            "internalid": "1"
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": "368",
    "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
    "columns": {
        "itemid": "04-PD",
        "displayname": "Product 1",
        "salesdescription": "Product 1",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        },
        "internalid": {
            "name": "368",
            "internalid": "368"
        },
        "unitprice": 35.29,
        "pricelevel": {
            "name": "pricelevel2",
            "internalid": "12"
        }
    }
}]
```

What Im trying to figure out is, is there an easy way to loop through the object and clone keys that are mapped to the pricelevel with the internalid of 1

and remove items that are not ?

as there could be several hundred in this set, im hoping there is an easy way to clone and strip out what I dont need..

any tips greatly appreciated

Comment: When you say clone what do you mean, duplicate but keep within the same data or to extract? Or to simply remove anything that is not internalid of 1?

Comment: Your objects do not have the same keys

Comment: Are you trying to do this? - `let myItems = JSON.parse(yourJson).filter(item => item.columns.internalid.internalid == "1");`. Note that you have objects with different properties "cols" and "columns". Also if you deserialize a JSON then filter it, I don't see the reason for cloning.

Comment: @LiamMacDonald - im trying to remove anything thats is not of internal id 1, and preserve the structure of what is there already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to provide recurse logic to selectively clone. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```js
var json = 
[{
    "id": "368",
    "type": "inventoryitem",
    "cols": {
        "id": "04-PD",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "salesdescription": "Product 1",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        },
        "internalid": {
            "name": "368",
            "internalid": "368"
        },
        "unitprice": 50.00,
        "pricelevel": {
            "name": "pricelevel1",
            "internalid": "1"
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": "368",
    "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
    "columns": {
        "itemid": "04-PD",
        "displayname": "Product 1",
        "salesdescription": "Product 1",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        },
        "internalid": {
            "name": "368",
            "internalid": "368"
        },
        "unitprice": 35.29,
        "pricelevel": {
            "name": "pricelevel2",
            "internalid": "12"
        }
    }
}];

function getMatchParentChildKeyVal(json, parentKey, matchKey, matchVal) {

  var out = [];
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < json.length; i++) {
  
    var matchRecord = parseMatchParent(json[i],null,parentKey); 
    if (matchRecord) {
        if (matchRecord[matchKey] == matchVal) {
            out.push(json[i]);
        }
    }
  }
  return out;
}
  
 function parseMatchParent(tree, parent, match) {
 
  for (var k in tree){
    if (tree.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       if (k == match) return tree[k];
        else if (typeof tree[k] == 'object') {
           var childMatch = parseMatchParent(tree[k],k, match);
           if (childMatch) return childMatch;
           }
    }
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 console.log(getMatchParentChildKeyVal(json,"pricelevel","internalid",'1'));
```

Comment: this is fantastic, this does exactly what i was trying to do and has also opened up a few things for me to learn